# How to get HTML code after rendering a view on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, render

I want to get the render "xxx" 's final HTML code to do something. I can change the file encoding from utf-8 to gb2312 then response it.

My question is, how to achieve this?

Comment: using javascript and the DOM? not sure I understand what you want though.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an `after_filter` for something like this.  Maybe along the lines of

```
  class ChangeEncodingFilter
    def self.filter(controller)
      controller.response.body = change_encoding(controller.response.body)
    end
  end

  class YourController < ActionController::Base
    after_filter ChangeEncodingFilter
  end
```

where you'll provide the `change_encoding` method to do the actual work.

Actually, it'll probably require mutation of other things in the response, but the point is that an after_filter can do things with the response just before it's sent.